# Why are my MT4 spreads higher?

Tags: foreign-exchange

I use forex.com as my forex broker.  Today, the majority of the spreads are less than 3 in the forex.com app.  However, the spreads in MT4 using my live forex.com login are a lot higher.  Why is this so?  Shouldn't the spreads be identical in both platforms since I am using the same account?

Comment: Could this be due to the infamous broker-side "Virtual Dealer Plugin"?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but it could be a sync issue. I've seen apps like WeBull, RobinHood, and MarketWatch all have differing prices on securities vs their online counterpart. Just yesterday the option chains on Robinhood's app vs the website were off a few dollars here and there. If in doubt I'd probably go with the website over the app.

Answer (score -1):

yes, when you download the MT4 then a demo account automatically opens from forex.com. and when you open a real account with any ECN broker you will get a 0pip spread from the ECN broker's side.

Comment: yes what? The question is why. Did you just want to spam the link?